# Unable to get the OnOff Flipswtich current state through JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

[This is my js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v9zHV/)

[and this is the original version of it](http://proto.io/freebies/onoff/)

Code is like:

HTML:

```
<fieldset  class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="xmonoffswitch">
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="xmonoffswitch">
        <div class="onoffswitch-inner">
            <div class="onoffswitch-active">Published</div>
            <div class="onoffswitch-inactive">Unpublished</div>
        </div>
        <div class="onoffswitch-switch"></div>
    </label>
</fieldset >
<div class="result"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.onoffswitch {
    position: relative; width: 182px;
    border: 0px;
    -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox {
    display: none;
}
.onoffswitch-label {
    display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #FFF3E4; border-radius: 50px;
}
.onoffswitch-inner {
    width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;
    -moz-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s; -webkit-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -o-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s; transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.onoffswitch-inner > div {
    float: left; width: 50%; height: 41px; padding: 0; line-height: 41px;
    font-size: 20px; color: white; font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-style: italic;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
}
.onoffswitch-inner .onoffswitch-active {
    padding-left: 14px;
    background-color: #F0B78B; color: #E67817;
}
.onoffswitch-inner .onoffswitch-inactive {
    padding-right: 14px;
    background-color: #F0B78B; color: #999999;
    text-align: right;
}
.onoffswitch-switch {
    width: 38px; height: 38px; margin:1.5px;
    background: #A1A1A1;
    border: 2px solid #FFF3E4; border-radius: 50px;
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 137px;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
    right: 0px;
    background-color: #E67817;
}
```

This is basically a switch button which has two states: published (On) and Unpublished (off). I want to fetch the current selected state through JQuery but not able to get it. Will anybody tell what could be the JQuery snippet for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script should be :

```
function getStatus(){
    // will return true in case of "ON" and false in case of "OFF"
    return $("input#xmonoffswitch").is(":checked");
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v9zHV/5/)**

Hope this will help !!

Answer (score 1):

you can check it by checking value of checkbox like this

```
   if($('.onoffswitch-checkbox').is(':checked'))​
   {
       alert('Published');
   } 
   else
   {
       alert('Unpublished');
   }
```

This demo will give you status of checkbox when you switch button

http://jsfiddle.net/v9zHV/4/